# qTip2 - Add a titlebar to my tooltip?

Tags: jquery, html, title, jscript, qtip2

i want to add a title to my qTip2 tooltip. Currently i have this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[title]').qtip({
        style: { classes: 'qtip-dark'}    
    });
});
</script>

<div title="TITLE">TEXT</div>
```

This gives me a text with a simple tooltip (http://beta.summonersindex.com/test.html). I just do not get managed to add a title, as it is shown on the demo page: http://qtip2.com/demos ('Add a title').
I searched for a solution for this a lot, but they are either out of date or not working for me. I hope you guys can help me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.someText').qtip({
        style: { classes: 'qtip-dark'},
        content: {
            text: 'Your text here',
            title: 'Your title here'
        }

    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="someText">TEXT</div>
```

Comment: thanks mate, this is working! another question: i have a custom style for my tooltips: `.si{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-family: "Verdana";
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
}` how do i customize the titlebar now? :)